# ASP.NET MVC 2 RC areas and shared models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas, areas

Once new area is created by the means of Visual Studio context menu, there are three folders: *Controllers, Models, Views*. Is it supposed that every area should have it's own model classes?  Or is it acceptable/widely-used/good for all areas to share the same model classes in the root *Models* folder?

My project differs Domain Model and View Model, so *Models* folder contain View Models.

And yes, several views of several areas seems to share the same View-Models some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your View Models are shared by several Areas, put them into `~/Models` - there is no any restiriction on that